# I am using regex in stream selector in streamsets but it is not working as expected

Tags: regex, streamsets

I am trying to partition data on wether it matches a regex or not.
The column contains the value  00000000081.48 and the expression is

str:matches(record:value('/OUT_HD_CURR_BAL'), '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')

But it is behaving as if the output is false. Is anything wrong with the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be

```js
str:regExCapture(record:value('/OUT_HD_CURR_BAL'), '([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)', 1)
```

If you need to get the boolean with `str:matches`, add `.*` around your expression:

```js
str:matches(record:value('/OUT_HD_CURR_BAL'), '.*[0-9]\.[0-9]+.*')
```

`str:matches` needs to match the string from start till end and `.*` matches any text.

Comment: This would return a string, I need a boolean value which string:matches() gives. Am I wrong in my understanding of these functions?